# Asistente para formulación de preguntas de usuarios nuevos

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva, preguntas, usuarios-nuevos

Leo en [StackOverflow Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com) que se acaba de poner en funcionamiento un asistente (Wizard) para guiar a los usuarios nuevos sobre como realizar una buena pregunta.

[The Ask Question Wizard is Live!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381671/579895)

Según lo describen,

> This is the biggest change we've made to the question asking experience on Stack Overflow since we started a little over ten years ago, and it's the result of a lot of hard work and collaboration with all of you in the community.

Traducción

> Este es el mayor cambio que hemos realizado a la experiencia de realizar preguntas en Stack Overflow desde que comenzamos hace poco mas de 10 años, y es el resultado de un montón de trabajo duro y la colaboración con todos vosotros en la comunidad.

La pregunta es...¿podemos tener ese asistente en esta nuestra comunidad? ¿Qué pasos debemos seguir para solicitarlo?

En mi opinión sería algo que ayudaría mucho para mejorar la calidad de las preguntas en Stack Overflow en español. ¿Qué opináis?

Comment: Opino que ya tardamos en tenerlo :)

Comment: "*En mi opinión sería algo que ayudaría mucho para mejorar la calidad de las preguntas en Stack Overflow en español*", en mi opinión si nos libra de las preguntas tipo "No se hacer esto, mira esta captura de pantalla" ya será un logro.

Comment: La cuestión es ir filtrando las preguntas malas y conseguir que o bien algunas no se lleguen a formular, o bien que lleguen a ver la luz de una forma más clara. Creo que es un _win win_: el usuario plantea algo con más posibilidades de obtener respuesta y la comunidad recibe una pregunta más clara.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo, es bueno tanto para los nuevos usuarios, que será mas difícil que acaben con preguntas cerradas y con muchos votos negativos, y para el sitio sin duda.

Comment: ¡ Basta de rodeos ! ¡ Lo queremos **ya** ! ¡ Lo **necesitamos** ya ! Y si viene acompañado de la prohibición de insertar imágnes hasta cierta reputación, **mucho mas mejor** :-)

Comment: Estuve mirando un poco el asistente, muy interesante. Creo que hasta la eligiría como interfaz por defecto.

Comment: LO NECESITAMOS,... NO HAY MAS QUE DECIR.. (perdon por gritar, me excite...)

Comment: Estoy entre juntas para intentar traer esta función a nuestra comunidad y a las demás comunidades internacionales. ;)

Comment: Estupendo @JuanM ! Creo que sería algo muy interesante para todos :)

Comment: Bien @JuanM!!!!! ya se lo recorde a nicolas, pero que no se olviden de los strings en transifex!

Comment: Era urgente, pero 3 años después y esta pregunta no tiene la etiqueta implementado. Ni siquiera estuvo "estado en revisión"

Answer (score 4):

Sin duda una herramienta mas que necesaria, entre las razones de su urgida presencia están:

- Una guía mas simple para los usuarios nuevos
- Una *feature* que le da varios pasos adelante a la plataforma
- Recordar que podemos recibir la información de distintos modos y a través de distintos medios

Sin lugar a dudas ya tenemos enlace altamente útiles pero que parece se verán muy beneficiados del *asistente*.

La comunidad de **SO en español** es muy activa guiando a los usuarios nuevos, pero el asistente sería algo muy recomendable de tener por:

- Los usuarios nuevos sabrán que es parte del sistema y no esta sujeto a opiniones, con lo cual no se sentirán algunos de ellos atacados
- Aunque la comunidad es altamente activa participando en el asesoramiento a los nuevos, tener un asistente que formaría parte del sistema propio facilita que la ayuda este de manera permanente
- Este punto dependerá de un período de tiempo y de los resultados que ofrezca, pero puede ser (y es solo mi opinión) un camino mas simple para que los nuevos y las nuevas aprendan a usar el sitio en una cantidad de tiempo considerablemente menor a la actual

Comment: Shadow.. estoy totalmente de acuerdo.. deja de marearme con los cambios de nick!

Comment: disculpa no era con esa intención @gbianchi y pues gracias por el comentario