# ¿Por qué no es obligatoria la lectura del Recorrido o de Cómo preguntar?

Tags: discusión, usuarios-no-registrados

Hagan esta prueba, entren en la página de preguntas/respuestas y miren a usuarios recién registrados. La grandísima mayoría tienen comentarios de otros usuarios en el que se recomienda esta lectura.

Es decir, la gran mayoría de nuevos usuarios no leen estos artículos, por lo que hace que se pierda mucha calidad en el sitio y muchas preguntas se queden como basura dada la poca calidad de la misma. Por esta razón me gustaría saber si existe algún motivo por el cual no exista la **obligación** de que se lean estos artículos.

Comment: Hagamos la pregunta opuesta: ¿obligar a leerlos aseguraría algo?

Comment: Es una buena pregunta, al menos aseguraría que los comentarios de la pregunta no se llenasen de las sugerencias de la lectura. He hecho una pequeña prueba: En la página principal de preguntas he visto todas las preguntas hechas por nuevos usuarios y 5 de 9 tenían un comentario recomendando que se hiciera el tour. Si fuera obligatorio al menos desaparecerían estos comentarios que realmente no aportan nada.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Recorrido obligatorio y eliminación de imágenes para usuarios nuevos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4003/recorrido-obligatorio-y-eliminaci%c3%b3n-de-im%c3%a1genes-para-usuarios-nuevos) o también [¿Se podría hacer más participativa e inmersiva la experiencia de la página de recorrido?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2244/83)

Comment: Yo creo que la clave es tener el [Asistente para formular preguntas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4024/83). Mientras tanto, veo con buenos ojos que la gente recomiende leer, aunque no tengo del todo claro que la información que haya sea especialmente útil para que un usuario con dudas específicas pueda situarse y preguntar correctamente. Probablemente lo de _Ejemplo mínimo completo y verificable_ sea la parte más recomendable.

Comment: Obligar no implica leer. Sabes cuantas veces un usuario dice que no sabe como aceptar una pregunta, cuando el recorrido lo dice especificamente, y segun sus medallas hizo el recorrido? o te dicen que no saben usar el sitio, pero les mandaste dos links de como usar el sitio, que ni siquiera se tomaron la molestia en leer?

Comment: Realmente creo que no existe la posibilidad de obligar a leer, pues prácticamente es como la licencia de instalación de x programa, nunca te tomas la molestia de leer, debido a que solo te interesa el producto y no te importa lo que implique (en la mayoría de las ocasiones). En cuanto a los comentarios creo que estos en realidad son útiles, ya que de alguna forma, el usuario comprende que su pregunta no es aceptada y algunos proceden a corregirla.

Comment: Fran, este es uno de los temas infinitos en Meta. Nunca va a resolverse. Una de las preguntas que, de hecho, son duplicadas, es mia, y me mataron a negativos. Pero me alegra ver que de vez en cuando se saque el tema a luz, aunque no se resuelva nada, al menos sabemos que esta presente. Uno de estos días, alguien (no tengo idea de quien podría ser) va hacer un cambio drástico en ese aspecto, y va dar resultados malos o buenos, pero al menos vamos a tener un punto de partida para cambiar cosas. Mientras tanto, seguira en el limbo para siempre.

Comment: Algo que si puedo decir, es una solución. La solución a este problema es: votar! Votar y votar como locos! (como "locos" es solo una expresión) Todos como comunidad! Eso te asegura que vamos a tener mas revisores y el sitio va a estar mejor moderado. Pero ya que eso involucra cambiar el pensamiento de la comunidad, entonces lo veo bastante difícil. Saludos y suerte!