# Propuesta indecente, modificar la página "hacer una pregunta"

Tags: discusión, revisión-de-pregunta, propuesta

Hace días superé los "500", ergo, accedí a las colas de revisión, y me encontré con un panorama, que si bien intuía, no dimensioné correctamente... la enorme cantidad de preguntas mal formuladas, y la sobrecarga de trabajo que por ello, cae sobre la espalda de los revisores.
Se que hay propuestas de modificar las guías para los usuarios, y voto a favor de todas, ya que lo que se lee en ellas, pasa por: correcto, poco claro, contradictorio...
Pero el verdadero problema, es que el usuario nuevo, o bien no leyó nada (la mayoría), o leyó algo pero no alcanzó a cubrir todos los matices que necesita conocer.
Acá va mi propuesta, es horrible, pero necesaria:

Cuando el futuro OP, le da a "publicar", le aparecen una serie de "alert", con mensajes cortos y claros, ejemplo:

"Test para evitar que tu pregunta sea eliminada"
-> [continuar]

"Tu pregunta es sobre programación?
-> [revisar pregunta]  [publicar]

"Estás seguro que explicas claramente lo que necesitas?
-> [revisar pregunta]  [publicar]

"Has adjuntado la parte relevante de tu código como texto?
-> [revisar pregunta]  [publicar]

Está de más decir que el texto del mensaje y la cantidad de ellos, los puse a modo de ejemplo, seguramente van a hacer mejores propuestas.
Esto debería aplicarse a usuarios que tengan menos de una cierta cantidad de puntos de reputación (30?).

Añadiría una segunda propuesta... para ganarme el odio de algunos:

- todo usuario habilitado, debe revisar al menos dos preguntas antes de realizar alguna actividad (excepto entrar al chat).

Esta segunda propuesta, reduciría enormemente la carga sobre los actuales revisores (desde mi pobre visión, siempre los mismos), lo que derivaría en una mayor calidad de las mismas.
***Se que así como está planteada, es inviable***, espero que sirva como semilla a una propuesta mejor, y que no perdamos tiempo debatiendo sobre la misma, hagamoslo sobre las propuesta viables... si es que aparecen!.

Comment: No sería una mala idea si no fuera porque dependes de que el usuario responda con sinceridad. Si hubiera una IA que detecte posibles preguntas de spam o no relacionadas a la programación se le podría impedir publicarlos directamente.

Comment: Me cuesta entender la primera propuesta. Estás proponiendo que el OP responda una serie de preguntas para ayudarlo a evaluar si su pregunta es de calidad? Eso, en mi opinión, suena bien (obviamente, como dice mateo, solo funcionaría si se responde con sinceridad). Pero el problema, es que no se puede comprimir todo el centro de ayuda en un solo test. Eso complicaría tanto publicar una pregunta que la gente se cansaría. Lo mejor es, como se está haciendo, un sistema automatico que detecte las preguntas de baja calidad y lo que no se detecta, trabajo a los revisores.

Comment: Sobre tu segunda propuesta, no es odio, es que no estoy de acuerdo. Por que a mi no me gusta revisar preguntas, omito la mayoría por miedo a equivocarme, y tendría que hacer esa revisión cada vez que quiera responder. Sería un dolor de cabeza. Lo mejor es que sea opcional, tal como está.

Comment: Además, ten en cuenta que hay muchos usuarios desesperados y/o egoistas que simplemente vienen por una respuesta. No quieren aportar, no quieren ayudar, no les importa las validaciones ni respetar a los demás, no les importa el contenido del centro de ayuda, no responden comentarios tratando de ayudar. Si obtienen su respuesta, se la llevan en sus garras y se van, sin pensar si quiera en agradecer de algún modo a quien dedicó su tiempo y esfuerzo en hacerles el código.

Comment: "todo usuario habilitado, debe revisar al menos dos preguntas antes de realizar alguna actividad (excepto entrar al chat)." No.., y basciamente, porque por mas habilitado que estes, NO ESTAS OBLIGADO a hacerlo de ninguna forma. Asi que no. es algo que lleva tiempo y no todo el mundo esta preparado, ni tiene las ganas de hacerlo. Grandes contestadores de preguntas no hacen una sola tarea de revision, y no tienen porque hacerla.

Comment: La primer parte, suena interesante.. pero entiendes que formamos parte de una red, y que toda la red, en ese sentido, tiene casi las mismas reglas, y que ese cambio, deberia ser aplicado a toda la red?

Comment: @Mateo, no se trata de sinceridad, sino de darle al OP los lineamientos más básicos, sin tener que remitirlo a donde no va a ir, el centro de ayuda, al ser cortos, los msj, seguramente se leerán, es verdad que el usuario puedo darle al botón sin revisar, pero ya estaría haciéndolo adrede, y creo que no es el caso de la mayoría, que pregunta mal por desconocimiento.

Comment: @DanteS., no se trara de que responda preguntas, sino de que vea el "cartel", tampoco me refiero acomprimir el centro de ayuda, solo los item que generan mayor cantidad de pregunta con formato incorrecto, creo que tres o cuatro, serían más que suficientes. **a mi no me gusta revisar preguntas**, me atrevo a hablar por los demás, a nadie le gusta, hay que hacerlo, como dije, así como lo presenté, es inaplicable, pero tampoco es justo que unos pocos dediquemos medio día a revisar, y otros revisen nada.

Comment: @gbianchi, estamos de acuerdo, no están obligados, la propuesta no es obligarlos, es imposible, sino crearles un condicional, ** no todo el mundo esta preparado, ni tiene las ganas de hacerlo**, no estoy preparado ni tengo ganas de hacerlo, le pongo todo el empeño, y si yo puedo, puede cualquiera, **y que ese cambio, debería ser aplicado a toda la red?**, no estoy al tanto de como se maneja esto, en lo personal no me interesa más que SOes, por mi, si se puede hacer la modificación solo aquí, gol.

Comment: El sistema ya avisa automaticamente cuando una pregunta tiene pinta de baja calidad. Por ejemplo, si hay un claro desequilibrio entre código y explicación, no permite publicar. Dije lo de comprimir el centro de ayuda por que sería un dolor de cabeza que tengas que pasar un test super largo para publicar. Pero eso de que se vean los primeros 3 o 4 me gusta! No es obligatorio revisar preguntas. El sitio es un voluntariado. Si querés contribuir, contribuis, si no no pasa nada.

Comment: Si, es injusto, pero no me gusta la idea de que me obligues (supongo que no soy el unico) a revisar preguntas. Yo le doy a omitir a muchas. No quiero ver 10 preguntas solo para revisar 2. Y encima todos los dias. Le pones todo el empeño, y eso vale y te agradesco en nombre del sitio, pero no todos tenemos esa voluntad. También es injusto que me hagas revisar preguntas cuando no tengo las ganas y estoy preparado. Si esa medida llegara a ser aprobada por la red, me iría del sitio. Y probablemente lo hagan todos los que no quieren/se animan a revisar preguntas.

Comment: @Dante S., no logro entenderte, tu revisas preguntas todos los días, tal vez no lo hagas desde el centro de revisión, pero lo haces, yo veo tu indicaciones, por otro lado, si te entiendo, no quiero no me gusta, a partir de hoy nadie revisa las colas... te la dejo picando.

Comment: *la propuesta no es obligarlos, es imposible, sino crearles un condicional* Eso es obligar. O sea, si querés estar en x escuela, debes seguir las normas. Si no te gusta, busca otra escuela o no vayas a una. Asi funciona obligar.

Comment: La segunda propuesta puede ser olvidable, es más, creo que si se puede sacar adelante la otra, hasta no sería necesaria.

Comment: Bueno, les pego una mirada rapida y algun que otro comentario. Pero no me la paso una hora en las colas de revisión. O lo hago pocas veces al año

Comment: Debes entender, que este sitio no funciona por si solo. todo cambio, es un cambio en toda la red de sitios (los mas de 150) y otros, funcionan con otras reglas y otras formas de trabajar. Me gusta tu cambio, no se, porque hay mil carteles en el medio, y no se molestan en mirar... No entiendo este enojo, las preguntas se cierran, se borran y listo.. si los nuevos no entienden, ya mas no puedo hacer...

Comment: @gbianchi, osea, no tenemos "poder" para llevar adelante un cambio en SOes?, si es así, nada más que hablar, decis: **hay mil carteles en el medio, y no se molestan en mirar**, bien, ya me entendiste, los tres (o 4) alert que propongo, les saltan a la cara, no necesitan buscarlos, no pueden esquivarlos.

Comment: Si se puede, pero el cambio tiene que ser para toda la red... es importante que entiendas como funciona este sitio junto con el resto.

Comment: @gbianchi, osea que tendría que convencer a medio planeta... creo que me rindo, ya que estás me quedó una duda, que ninguno de uds, contestó, eso de "pregunta en espera" no existe más?... es solo curiosidad.

Comment: Yo tengo la misma duda, pues en mis 3 años en el sitio, no vi que una pregunta estuviera explicitamente en espera.

Comment: En teoría no hay diferencia entre una pregunta cerrada y una en espera https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

Comment: Lo primero que propones se parece a esto https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4024/asistente-para-formulaci%c3%b3n-de-preguntas-de-usuarios-nuevos que por lo que se lee es una características que si es parte de la Red

Comment: @Yussef el centro de ayuda dice algo que no vi pasar nunca: una pregunta que pasa de espera a cerrada luego de 5 dias. Asi que si debe de haber una diferencia. Para mi, está hablando de una vieja función del siti que ya no está vigente.

Comment: @Yussef, es parte de la red... de la otra, acá ni noticias.

Comment: El "Ask Wizard" está implementado, al menos, en [so] y [es.so] (no sé las que están es otros idiomas). ¿De qué otra red hablás? La red es [se].

Comment: @padaleiana, a ti tal vez te aparezca algo como [esto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7HRk.png) al formular una pregunta, a mi no.

Comment: Está del lado derecho de donde redactás la pregunta... Tiene otra interfaz.

Comment: @padaleiana, tu tienes más experiencia que yo, y probablemente estés en lo cierto, pero yo entiendo que el cambio, fue hacer que la pantalla en la cual redactas, sea la que te va guiando, no lo que hay fuera de ella.

Comment: Ni te imaginás la cantidad de cambios de interfaz que hubo en estos años... Muchos odiados, de hecho.